# Inject environment variables plugin is passing value as "12345"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using "Inject environment variables" Jenkins plugin to pass values to child jobs.  Property file name is config.Today_date(eg. config.0403) and it has two parameters in it 1. change list(eg. 175444) 2.  today's date(eg. 04032014). In child job Properties file path is config.${Today_date}($Today_date is predefined parameter in parent job).

First issue is: it error out saying config."Today_date" do not exist. I went to location and found property file is there and realized that child job is searching properties file as config."Today_date"(config."0403")and actual name of file is config.today_date

Second issue is: if i put property file name as config.0403(today_date) in Properties file path, Then it successfully locate the file but where ever it use parameters from this file, it use them as "0403" & "175444"

Please advise how i can solve "" issue at both locations.

Thanks !!

Comment: In what format are you storing the values in the properties file?

Comment: Also, if it's just 2 values, why not pass the values with Parameterized Trigger Plugin instead? Seems to me you already have to do that anyways to pass the value of `$Today_date` from parent to child

Comment: Hi Slav, I am storing value as Today_date="20052015", These values are produced by a shell script which run inside parent job. So to pass value to  job i have to use Inject environment plugin. Also some scheduled child jobs do not run same day.

Comment: Don't use quotes in the properties file, and you won't have quotes in your output